# Slow page Loads When Using Dynamic Coding

Tags: shortcode, performance

I have written code to get certain tags, and then show the products that have those tags.

This is the code:

```
$tag_string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {

        $tag_to_use = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_tag_to_use_'.$i.'_'.$j, true);
        $tag_string = $tag_to_use ? $tag_string .= $tag_to_use . ',' : $tag_string .= '';

    }
}

if ( substr( $tag_string, -1) == ',' ) {
    $tag_string = rtrim( $tag_string, ',' );
}

echo do_shortcode( '[products tag="' . $tag_string . '"]' );

}
```

When I run th code, I get slow page loads.

When I change this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[products tag="' . $tag_string . '"]' );
```

To this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[products tag="test,test1"]' );
```

The page loads fast.

Why is that happening, and how can I fix it? If any more information is needed, tell me and I'll update the question.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump( $tag_string );` ? And instead of calling `do_shortcode()`, you could just directly call the function which handles the `products` shortcode.

Comment: This is the output of `var_dump( $tag_string );`  -  `string(22) "test,test1,test2,Aztec" `. What is the function it calls?

Comment: And is it still slow with `echo do_shortcode( '[products tag="test,test1,test2,Aztec"]' )` ?

Comment: Yes. I have changed the shortcode to this: `[products limit="8" paginate="true" tag="' . $tag_string . '"]` and now it loads fine. Do you know how I could change it to infinte scroll instead of pagination?

Comment: It's not that I don't know, but try searching for an existing question/answer/solution - or a plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/)..

Comment: And if you're referring to the WooCommerce products shortcode, then `WC_Shortcodes::products()` is the callback for the `products` shortcode. And by default, there's no limit to the number of products shown (i.e. `limit` is `-1`). So you may have lots of products in those tags, which caused the slow page loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if it is the root of the problem, but the thing that I noticed is that your code ends up calling `get_post_meta` quite many times (*64? 8 loops within 8 loops, yes?*) for the same post.

Perhaps you could get all of the post meta just once, before the for loop. Then within your loop use `isset()` or `! empty()` to check if the data exists.

Something along these lines,

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID); // This returns an array with all the data in position 0, if I remember correctly
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
    if ( isset( $post_meta[0]['_tag_to_use_'.$i.'_'.$j] ) ) {
      $tag_to_use = $post_meta[0]['_tag_to_use_'.$i.'_'.$j];
      // The meta value might be in a array with the position 0, var_dump $tag_to_use to see if this is the case
      // $tag_to_use = $post_meta[0]['_tag_to_use_'.$i.'_'.$j][0];
      $tag_string = $tag_to_use ? $tag_string .= $tag_to_use . ',' : $tag_string .= '';
    }
  }
}
```

Use `var_dump` to check that you get the array indexes correct and `maybe_unserialize()` the meta data, if needed.

I don't know if this is just broscience and wishful thinking, but maybe it's worth the try. You can of course use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to get a rough idea, if the loop above is faster than the original.

Comment: uh, what's "broscience" ?